# How to go to another window on button click?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have several windows in my .py file so that the user can switch to another window on button click. However, I don't want the window to open as a new one, a.k.a. pop up. Rather, I want the old window (`tkWindow1`) to simply be replaced by the new one (`tkWindow2`). How can I do something like that?

```
def download:
    function body

tkWindow1 = Tk()

button = Button(tkWindow1, command=someFunction)
```

like this:

[image: gif]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to create a function or class to define the contents of the window before and after the click, and then just delete the original contents and replace with the new.

```
import tkinter as tk

class LandingPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Enter", command=begin_download)
        button.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

class DownloadPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Your download has begun!")
        label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

def begin_download():
    for child in root.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    download_page = DownloadPage(root)
    download_page.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def main():
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x400")
    root.configure()
    landing_page = LandingPage(root)
    landing_page.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Bryan! Such a simple and concise answer. You defined two frames, then defined what happens upon clicking the button (destroy the old frame and fill in the new frame), and finally you appended that as a command to the button function. Amazing answer! Thank you again.