# TypeError: create() argument 1 must be str or None, not Tk

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently struggling with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\facrec\Desktop\gui.py", line 204, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\facrec\Desktop\gui.py", line 200, in main
    firstframe = FirstFrame(root)
  File "C:\Users\facrec\Desktop\gui.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\facrec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
TypeError: create() argument 1 must be str or None, not Tk
```

I tried the solution in [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/ajycqv/trying_to_make_a_calculator_that_switches_frames/eezwrb6/?context=3), but it didn't work. (The linked solution is to put `from tkinter import *` at the top of the file.) I'm not sure what the `create()` function is in this case, and why it matters that it should be a string or None and not Tk. Is the problem with Tk vs tk? Or is it with some incorrectly defined function?

This is my script:

```
from pathlib import Path


from tkinter import Canvas, Entry, Text, Tk, Button, PhotoImage

OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path("./assets")


def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)
class FirstFrame(Tk, Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        frame1 = Tk()

        frame1.geometry("1084x770")
        frame1.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")

        canvas = Canvas(
            frame1,
            bg = "#FFFFFF",
            height = 770,
            width = 1084,
            bd = 0,
            highlightthickness = 0,
            relief = "ridge"
        )

        canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        canvas.create_rectangle(
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1084.0,
            770.8444213867188,
            fill="#2E3440",
            outline="")

        frame1.resizable(False, False)
        frame1.mainloop()

class SecondFrame(Tk, Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        frame2 = Tk()
        frame2.geometry("1440x1024")
        frame2.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")

        canvas = Canvas(
            frame2,
            bg = "#FFFFFF",
            height = 1024,
            width = 1440,
            bd = 0,
            highlightthickness = 0,
            relief = "ridge"
        )

        canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        canvas.create_rectangle(
            0.0,
            0.0,
            1440.0,
            1024.0,
            fill="#2E3440",
            outline="")

        frame2.resizable(False, False)
        frame2.mainloop()

def first_to_second():
    for child in root.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    secondframe = SecondFrame(root)
    secondframe.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    
def main():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    root.configure()
    firstframe = FirstFrame(root)
    firstframe.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Why do you create a custom widget inherits from both `Tk` and `Frame`?  Also why do you create another instance of `Tk()` inside the class?

Comment: Where do you get the frame from? When I tried to reproduce the error, it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Hello! I've been following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71041474/18084172). I just made up these frames. Because the frames differ in names, I equaled each to Tk() inside each respective class. They ran fine without the def function, but when I introduced the def function, I started getting the error. I think there's something wrong with the three lines of the def function.

Comment: I don' think the problem with is the smallcase or uppercase Tk since you say that it worked correctly without the func. I don't get which function are you talking about though? The main problem I can say is , you defined the initials of the class as Tk, frame while it is used as tk.frame in the example you have shown. (As I have said use the version that makes it work. )tk or Tk but from the documentation here: @https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html I think it is Tk. Anyway can you try Tk.frame I think that's the problem here.

Comment: When I did that, it gave me a new error: `TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str`. I removed Tk.frame, and I got another error `TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)`. Python is confusing me: what should I do? I just want a frame inside a class.

Comment: Do you understand the answer to your other question (link in your comment)? If yes, you should know how to do it.

Comment: I found it. There is an error in the example, it should just be Frame, not Tk.Frame. That fixes it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is very wrong to inherit from `Tk` and `Frame`, and also create a new instance of `Tk`. It's definitely not doing what you think it's doing.